# Data Tables prevent autofit of columns based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Based on this code

```
var table = $('#tbl-sample').DataTable( {
    "destroy": true,
    "aaSorting" : [],
    "searching" : false
});
```

This one creates a datatable look on my html table the problem is it overwrites the html style which is 100% width by making the column fit based on header or even on the data how can i prevent it? I tried this but its not working

`"autoWidth": false`

Here is my table

```
<table id = "tbl-sample" name = "tbl-sample" class="table table-hover cell-border tablefont">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#bccad6">Time In</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bccad6">Time Out</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bccad6">Expense</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bccad6">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <th colspan="4" bgcolor="#bccad6"></th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to remove `"destroy": true,`

Comment: still the same and also try with and without `"autoWidth": false`

Comment: Did you created your table (in your dom) before doing this ?

Comment: what do you mean sir? I have a table alreay created with headers

Comment: Can you add your table to your question please ?

Comment: @JeremyM. sure for a minute

Comment: done sir already posted